# How to overwrite operand value of x86 `movq` instruction via c pointer in linux kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

Currently I have written a code segment using assembly on one page `pageA` in linux kernel.The code is

```
SYM_CODE_START(sr_function)
    movq $0, %rdx
    movq $0x7ffff7fc6000, %rsi 
    movq $0x19016bc83000, %rcx
    movq $9, %rdx
    movq $0, %rdx
    jmp goto_fce_func
SYM_CODE_END(sr_function)
```

At run time , I would like to overwrite the first operad of `mov` instruction via c pointer, For example, I map the page `pageA` to kernel space using `kmap(pageA)`.

That means, Now the first instruction `movq $0, %rdx` has the address for example `0x1000`.

I would like to use C pointer to：

1. change the first operand from value `0` to `0x19016bc83000` for the first `mov instruction` `movq $0, %rdx`
2. change the first operand from value `0x7ffff7fc6000` to `0x19016bc74000` for the second`mov instruction` `movq $0x7ffff7fc6000, %rsi`
3. change the first operand from value `0x19016bc83000` to `0` for the third`mov instruction` `movq $0x19016bc83000, %rcx`

Do you know how could i do this?

the Disassembly of this code segment by using `objdump -D` shows

```
0000000000001000 <sr_function>:
    1000:   48 c7 c2 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdx
    1007:   48 be 00 60 fc f7 ff    movabs $0x7ffff7fc6000,%rsi
    100e:   7f 00 00 
    1011:   48 b9 00 30 c8 6b 01    movabs $0x19016bc83000,%rcx
    1018:   19 00 00 
    101b:   48 c7 c2 09 00 00 00    mov    $0x9,%rdx
    1022:   48 c7 c2 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdx
    1029:   e9 de ef ff ff          jmpq   c <goto_fce_func>
```

Comment: In disassemble you may find offsets of bytes which contain instruction parameters which you want to modify. Use these offsets at runtime for find bytes and perform modifications.

Comment: Be aware that on some architectures code pages may be set non-writable and data pages may be noexec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
1000:   48 c7 c2 00 00 00 00    mov    $0x0,%rdx
1007:   48 be 00 60 fc f7 ff    movabs $0x7ffff7fc6000,%rsi
100e:   7f 00 00 
1011:   48 b9 00 30 c8 6b 01    movabs $0x19016bc83000,%rcx
```

---

Your first instruction will be very difficult to patch, because you want to patch it with a 64-bit value but it's currently encoded to deal with a 32-bit immediate.

Let's take the instruction - `mov $0x0, %rdx` and understand its encoding byte-by-byte:

- `0x48` - this prefix byte specifies that the instruction to follow is 64-bit sized.
- `0xc7` - this specifies that the instruction is a `mov reg, imm32` instruction
- `0xc2` - this specifies the target register (encoded in the bottom 3 bits) - in this case, `rdx` (which is register number 2)
- `0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00` - encode your 32-bit immediate in **little endian**.

When this happens, the top 32 bits of `rdx` are zeroed out anyways - but this prevents you from patching the immediate directly, because you need access to all 64 bits.

The simplest solution for this is to patch your assembly instruction to be `movabs $0, %rdx` - for which the assembler will output a patchable instruction.

---

And as for the following two `movabs` instructions - they have a similar encoding, except that their second byte (`0xbe` for the first and `0xb9` for the second) encode the destination register **inside the byte**: they belong to the `0xb8 + r` opcodes, where the `+r` encodes the destination register: `0xbe == 0xb8  + 6` and `rsi` is register number 6, `0xb9 == 0xb8 + 1` and rcx is register number 1.

---

Once you have three instructions that each have a 64-bit immediate to patch, the patching itself is easy. You need a `char*` variable that points to the instruction you want to patch - then you want to increment it by the appropriate amount of bytes so that it points to the offset - and then you want to cast it to a `uint64_t*` - and patch it appropriately.

```
char* ptr; // points to e.g. the last movabs instructions
ptr += 2; // skip over 0x48 and 0xb9
*((uint64_t*)ptr) = 0; // zero out the entire immediate
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, This really helped me. Beyoud the topic, I was wondering, where do you leaned the encoding stuff? Could you please provide me some links so that I could learn more about encoding of assembly?

Comment: Sure - probably the best thorough way to learn is to read Chapter 2 of Volume 2 of Intel's x86 SDM: https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/download/intel-64-and-ia-32-architectures-sdm-combined-volumes-2a-2b-2c-and-2d-instruction-set-reference-a-z.html - and once you've understood how basic encoding works, this website is a great x86 reference - http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html - and in general, reverse engineering x86 assemblies without using a decompiler is a great way to learn more through hands-on experience.

Comment: `orq $0, %rdx` also only takes a 32-bit immediate, so I don't see how that'll help.  AFAIK the only way to load a 64-bit immediate in one instruction is `movabs`.  If you get to modify the original assembly, can you not just do `movabs $0, %rdx`, assuming you can prevent the assembler from "optimizing" it into `mov`?

Comment: @NateEldredge You're right on both accounts :) I'll fix this